# Visual Studio Community 2015 Access Violation exiting Hello World

Tags: debugging

I get an Access Violation when exiting (in debug mode) the simplest application. 
This is my C++ program; win32 console application, empty project, no precompiled headers, no SDL checks:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When in debug mode (F5) it results:
Exception thrown at 0x778AB2D5 (ntdll.dll) in hello.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x7179FFFF.

I have repaired and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 community and now installed VS Community Update 2RC with same result. No problem when starting without debugging (Ctrl+F5)

When debugging I can enter exe_common.inl, till line 264, where the exception is thrown (18 times):

```
if (!__scrt_is_managed_app())
            exit(main_result);  // -->> here
```

Editing:
And the Call Stack shows:

> ```
> ntdll.dll!_RtlFreeHeap@12 ()    Unknown
> KernelBase.dll!_LocalFree@4 ()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!7420ec83()    Unknown
> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for a2hooks32.dll]   
> a2hooks32.dll!7421014f()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!74207565()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!742078b1()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!74206e6d()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!7420658d()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!742037fd()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!7421ac69()    Unknown
> a2hooks32.dll!7421ad4f()    Unknown
> [External Code]
> ```

Any clue? Do someone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well; shame on me...
I am responding my own question because it's possible to clarify the same issue to others. I must say that the problem is not related to Visual Studio 2015 but others Windows compilers (in fact, debuggers) also.

I asked the owner of a2hooks32.dll, Emsisoft Anti-Malware maker, and the support guy immediately sent the answer:

> ... the Behavior Blocker will attempt to look up the hash for the file to verify it, while blocking the executable's ability to function momentarily. This is causing an access violation, apparently, because of the connected debugger that is ALSO accessing the file.

Well, that was it. Whaitlisting the executable in the anti-malware solved my preoccupation.